# Locally File upload API in .net core is working but not in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, invalid-argument

I have developed in .net web API working locally fine. But when hosted in Azure App Service (Linux) giving error "Invalid argument", status: 200, statusText: "OK"

Comment: Can you update the uploaded code snippet in the post, so we can help you.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).